# Understanding types in Elm

Tags: javascript, types, elm

Trying to learn Elm with a background in JS and little experience in strongly- and statically-typed languages, I find that the major difficulty revolves around the type syntax (and what types are useful for in Elm generally). Unfortunately, I don't find the docs very helpful in this respect.

If I take the simple example here: http://elm-lang.org/examples/buttons, the line:

```
type Msg = Increment | Decrement
```

defines a union type `Msg` as "being" either `Increment` or `Decrement`. It seems to suggest that `Increment` and `Decrement` are types too. What are they exactly? (They're not defined elsewhere in the example, nor are they predefined types).

Then, they are used in the `view` function as an argument of `onClick`. Now, they seem to act like a kind of "message" (whatever that means). In JS, this would probably be achieved by assigning a value to a (mutable) variable in each case -- which of course can't be the Elm way. So, is the way types work related to the topic of immutability?

The `view` function:

```
view model =
  div []
    [ button [ onClick Decrement ] [ text "-" ]
    , div [] [ text (toString model) ]
    , button [ onClick Increment ] [ text "+" ]
    ]
```

I think this potentially opens a broader topic (if someone can point to useful links, thanks!) but my question is: what are `Increment` and `Decrement` here? How do they fit in Elm's type system?

Comment: The Elm Guide has a more detailed discussion on [Union Types here](https://guide.elm-lang.org/types/union_types.html).

Comment: I also notice that the defined union type `Msg` is not used elsewhere in the example. Does it have to be defined this way just so we are allowed to use the `case` statement in the `update` function?

Comment: You don't see `Msg` anywhere else because the other functions aren't annotated in this example (in Elm they don't _have_ to be but it can be very helpful to annotate your functions). Assuming `Model` is a type alias of `Int`, the type annotations should be: `view : model -> Html Msg` and `update : Msg -> Model -> Model`

Comment: Did you mean `view : Model -> Html Msg`?

Comment: Whoops, yes, that should be uppercase `Model`. StackOverflow won't let me change it now. Good catch. It will still compile with lowercase but it has a different meaning. Lowercase in the annotation means roughly anything can go in there but you'd typically see something like `a` or `b`, as in `view : a -> Html Msg` (by way of convention)

Comment: And how do you explain `Html Msg`? Does `Html` refer to the imported module? And the `Msg` part? (I suppose it's the same kind of construction as `List Int` -- but this one is intuitive: a list of integers).

Comment: [This conversation is continued in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124879/discussion-between-nicolas-le-thierry-dennequin-and-chad-gilbert)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Increment` and `Decrement` are data constructors. You can think of them as OO constructors, they can have parameters and more importantly, one can tell them apart.

You are correct that they are indeed a message; but since they have no parameters, they are no different from enumeration values. The fact that a value is immutable has little to do with it. C/C++/Java also support enumerations.

In this specific case, you can even think of `Msg` as fancy names for a `boolean`.

Sum types are actually mostly like union types in C. The difference is that in Elm it stores which of the options it is. Elm takes these concepts from Haskell.

Comment: I've started learning Haskell recently, and I was actually motivated to do so from stumbling upon Elm, when I realised where much of Elm's syntax comes from. I believe unions are called algebraic data types in Haskell? Anyway, I digress - good answer!